How can I play a custom tone using a downloaded audio file?
In my app, I have multiple sound files fetched from the server, and these files can change based on server configurations. When an FCM notification is received, I need to set the downloaded tone file as the notification tone. However, the FCM documentation specifies that the file must be placed in the res/raw folder, and since the downloaded file is available in the document directory, the notification sound is not being played.
This issue has specifically been encountered on Android.
I used the audio player to play the downloaded file, but there's an issue with this workaround. If the media volume is muted, the audio player sound doesn't play.
Is there any other way to handle this issue without using an audio player?
